# Same regex in perl and sed work differently

Tags: perl, cyrillic

Okay, maybe something wrong with unicode or etc, but the code tells everything:

```
$ cat leo
сказывать
ссказываю
сказав
BladeMight@Chandere ~ 23:24:58
$ cat leo | perl -pe 's/^с+каз/Рассказ/g'
Рассказывать
ссказываю
Рассказав
BladeMight@Chandere ~ 23:25:00
$ cat leo | sed -r 's/^с+каз/Рассказ/g'
Рассказывать
Рассказываю
Рассказав
```

I have file `leo`, contents in cyrillic, so i wanted to replace wrong places with the regex `^с+каз` in `perl -pe`, but it replaces only the ones that have only 1 `с`(cyrillic one), e.g. `+` does nothing in this case(and for non-cyrillic it works fine), although in `sed -r` it works perfectly. Why could that be?

Comment: You'll also want to avoid the [useless `cat`](/questions/11710552/useless-use-of-cat).

Comment: Tip: No need to involve `cat`. You can use `perl -pe'...' leo`

Comment: @ikegami I'll note that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perl needs to be told that your source code is UTF-8 (`-Mutf8`) and that it should treat stdin and stdout as UTF-8 (`-CS`).

```
$ cat leo | perl -Mutf8 -CS -pe 's/^с+каз/Рассказ/g'
Рассказывать
Рассказываю
Рассказав
```

Comment: NOTE: `use utf8` is necessary only if inside of the code used `utf8` encoding (for example search pattern in this particular case). An options `-CS` is required practically anytime when `utf8` input/output takes place.